# Python in proccess of geting to pig game

Tags: python

Issue occurred right after I added the `and x= "J1234"`: I don't know what's going on.

```
original = ""
if len(original) > 0 and x = "J123":
    raw_input("Enter a word:")
    original = raw_input('word')
    print "original"
else:
    print "empty"
x.isalpha()
```

Comment: You need double `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're getting a `SyntaxError`. To fix this, change:

```
x = "J123":
```

to...

```
x == "J123":
```

In Python the former is for setting values and the latter is for checking them. Therefore when you use this the wrong way round the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python  I am on conditioanl and check on PGlatin game 5/11

Comment: @user3453762 When I started programming about a year ago, I wrote this: http://pastebin.com/YfbzArws if you are interested. It is a Pig-Latin translator similar to this.